# Entanglement entropy's role in quantum information

Tags: entanglement, entropy, information-theory

I am just new to the concepts of entanglement entropy and how it is used to measure the entanglement in systems. I want to know the role of entanglement entropy in quantum information, in general.

Comment: that's a bit too broad. The answer to "the role of entanglement entropy in general" could very well be [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_of_entanglement). Could you be more specific about what exactly you find unclear in the explanation there?

Answer (score 1):

Considering your question is not specific, you can take a look at Chapters 10 (classical entropy) and 11 (quantum entropy) of [this book](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.1445).

Quantum entanglement entropy as we know it comes from classical Shannon theory. Claude Shannon introduced entropy in order to quantify information. You can read his paper [here](http://people.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/home/text/others/shannon/entropy/entropy.pdf).